# Logrotate error: No file found

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, logging, logrotate

One of our servers has a recurring error message for Logrotate.

> /etc/cron.daily/logrotate: ERROR  No file found for /usr/local/Zend/apache2/logs/error_log

Log rotation is working normally for the folder that it should look into. The error mentions a folder that is not monitored.

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log /var/log/apache2/*/*.log {
  daily
  rotate 50
  compress
  delaycompress
  missingok
  notifempty
  sharedscripts
  postrotate
        /usr/local/Zend/apache2/bin/apachectl graceful
  endscript
}
```

When I grep for `error_log` in the apache folder I find the following:

> conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf: ErrorLog "/usr/local/Zend/apache2/logs/error_log"
>   conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf: ErrorLog /www/phones/logs/error_log

Both these folders are not monitored by the httpd logrotate script. 
We don't use SSL, so there is no log there. The phones log is there but it not rotated currently. I've grepped the logrotate.d folder to see if some other logrotate config file monitors the apache folder, but no result.

Below the contents of /etc/logrotate.conf

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp and btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0600 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
```

Output of `/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf -d`

```
reading config file /etc/logrotate.conf
including /etc/logrotate.d
reading config file dirmngr
reading config info for /var/log/dirmngr/dirmngr.log 
reading config file fail2ban
reading config info for /var/log/fail2ban.log 
reading config file httpd
reading config info for /var/log/apache2/*.log /var/log/apache2/*/*.log 
reading config file ppp
reading config info for /var/log/ppp/connect-errors 
reading config file psacct
reading config info for /var/account/pacct 
reading config file rpm
reading config info for /var/log/rpmpkgs 
reading config file rsyslog
reading config info for /var/log/messages /var/log/secure /var/log/maillog /var/log/spooler /var/log/boot.log /var/log/cron 
reading config file snmpd
reading config info for /var/log/snmpd.log 
reading config file wpa_supplicant
reading config info for /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log 
reading config file yum
reading config info for /var/log/yum.log 
reading config info for /var/log/wtmp 
reading config info for /var/log/btmp 

Handling 12 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/dirmngr/dirmngr.log  weekly (4 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/dirmngr/dirmngr.log
  log /var/log/dirmngr/dirmngr.log does not exist -- skipping

rotating pattern: /var/log/fail2ban.log  30720 bytes (4 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/fail2ban.log
  log does not need rotating
not running postrotate script, since no logs were rotated

rotating pattern: /var/log/apache2/*.log /var/log/apache2/*/*.log  after 1 days (50 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/apache2/access.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/apache2/voip-access.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/apache2/voip-error.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/apache2/zoo-access.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/apache2/zoo-error.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/apache2/error.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/apache2/trs_error.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/apache2/market-access.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/apache2/market-error.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/apache2/shop/staging-access.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/apache2/shop/staging-error.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/apache2/shop/shop-access.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/apache2/shop/shop-error.log
  log does not need rotating
not running postrotate script, since no logs were rotated

rotating pattern: /var/log/ppp/connect-errors  after 1 days (5 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/ppp/connect-errors
  log /var/log/ppp/connect-errors does not exist -- skipping

rotating pattern: /var/account/pacct  after 1 days (31 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/account/pacct
  log does not need rotating
not running postrotate script, since no logs were rotated

rotating pattern: /var/log/rpmpkgs  weekly (4 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/rpmpkgs
  log does not need rotating

rotating pattern: /var/log/messages /var/log/secure /var/log/maillog /var/log/spooler /var/log/boot.log /var/log/cron  weekly (4 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/messages
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/secure
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/maillog
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/spooler
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/boot.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/cron
  log does not need rotating
not running postrotate script, since no logs were rotated

rotating pattern: /var/log/snmpd.log  weekly (4 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/snmpd.log
  log /var/log/snmpd.log does not exist -- skipping
not running postrotate script, since no logs were rotated

rotating pattern: /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log  30720 bytes (4 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log
  log /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log does not exist -- skipping

rotating pattern: /var/log/yum.log  yearly (4 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/yum.log
  log does not need rotating

rotating pattern: /var/log/wtmp  monthly (1 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/wtmp
  log does not need rotating

rotating pattern: /var/log/btmp  monthly (1 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/btmp
  log /var/log/btmp does not exist -- skipping
```

What causes this error? I have no idea where to look.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start from the beginning:

1. Check the call for `logrotate` inside `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` to see if some special conf file is used. Traditionally `/etc/logrotate.conf` is used.
2. Inside your `.conf` file, look for `include` directive. You should have one: `include /etc/logrotate.d` and grep this directory for `error_log`. Also, check that there is no system specific logs declared inside the `.conf` file.

Have you found anything?

If you didn't, I suggest that you run the `logrotate` command found inside the `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`, adding the `-d` switch to it.

Comment: The normal logrotate.conf is used. I've copied the contents in the question. Nothing refers to error_log. I don't see the btmp logfile from the logrotate.conf file in /var/log.

Comment: Running `/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf -d` results in lots of output, but no mention of `error_log` and nothing needs rotating. It mentions the missing btmp, and then skips it.

Comment: @SPRBRN sorry I haven't explained myself very well. What I meant, was: inside the `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` script you will have a call to the `logrotate` binary. Mine is `/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf >/dev/null 2>&1`. If you have the same, you should launch `/usr/sbin/logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf`

Comment: Thanks! I saw the mistake myself, have changed my comment, but didn't find anything there.

Comment: @SPRBRN that's awkward. Please post the output of the debug command.

Comment: See the question!

Comment: @SPRBRN Your output log is clean and as you've figured there is no mention of a `/usr/local/Zend/apache2/logs/error_log`. How did you get the error line `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate: ERROR No file found for /usr/local/Zend/apache2/logs/error_log`? Please be sure that you've issued the debug command on the right host and that no config files have changed.